# How do you show $\int \limits_{X \times Y} f(x,y)\, d\lambda < \infty$ if $\int \limits_{X} \int \limits_{Y} f(x,y) \,d\nu \,d\mu < \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f: X\times Y \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ is a measurable function with respect to the product measure $\lambda$ ( $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ and $(Y, \tau, \nu)$ are complete measure spaces).

Suppose $\int \limits_{X} \int \limits_{Y} f(x,y) \,d\nu\, d\mu < \infty$.  I want to show $\int \limits_{X \times Y} f(x,y)d\lambda < \infty$.

Here is my idea:

Since $\int \limits_{X} \int \limits_{Y} f(x,y) \,d\nu \,d\mu < \infty$, then the map $x \rightarrow \int \limits_{Y} f(x,y)\, d\nu < \infty$ a.e. $d\mu(x)$, that is, for almost all $x$, $\int \limits_{Y} f(x,y) \,d\nu < \infty$.  Now, for those $x$ such that $\int \limits_{Y} f(x,y) \,d\nu < \infty$, we have $f(x,y) < \infty$ a.e. $d\nu(y)$.  That is, for almost all $x$, we have that $f(x,y) < \infty$ for almost all $y$.

I think I want to conclude that $f(x,y) < \infty$ a.e. $d\lambda$, because this would imply $\int \limits_{X \times Y} f(x,y) \,d\lambda < \infty$.  How can I conclude this?  Thanks for your help.

**Edit**:  Is it as simple as saying since $f(x,y) < \infty $ a.e. $d\nu(y)$ a.e. $d\nu(x)$, then if $x\not \in N$ for a set $N$ of measure $0$, and $y \not \in K$ for a set $ K$ of measure $0$, then $(x, y) \not \in N \times K$ implies $f(x,y) < \infty$?

Comment: Isn't this just Fubini/Tonelli's Theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions?

Comment: @gerw I'm reviewing my notes from Analysis.  We first learned Fubini's theorem as it applied to functions in $L^{1}(d\lambda)$.  Then, as we moved on to functions not necessarily in $L^{1}(d\lambda)$ (i.e., moving toward Tonelli's theorem), I thought the professor said that in general, if the iterated integral is finite, then so is the integral wrt the product measure.  This was before we proved or even stated Tonelli's theorem.  I haven't been able to prove this.

Comment: @gerw Also, I don't think we are necessarily in $\sigma$-finite spaces.

Comment: @user46944 are you assuming $f \ge 0$, or what do you mean?

Comment: @T.A.E. Yeah, the codomain of $f$ is $[0,\infty]$ and $f$ is measurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a classical example. Let $\nu$ be Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ and let $\mu$ be counting measure on $[0,1]$. Both are complete measures. Then define $f(x,y)=0$ if $x \ne y$ and $f(x,x)=1$ for $0 \le x \le 1$. This function is jointly measurable. Check the three integrals: 1 with respect to the product measure and the other two iterated integrals. You get three different values. (By the way: knowing the two iterated integrals are not the same tells you the value of the integral with respect to the product measure.)

Comment: I didn't know how to calculate $\int \limits_{X \times Y} f(x,y) \,d\lambda$, but, if I calculated them right, the other two integrals should be:  $\int \limits_{X} \int \limits_{Y} f(x,y) \,d\nu \,d\mu = 0$ and $\int \limits_{Y} \int \limits_{X} f(x,y) \,d\mu \,d\nu = 1$

Comment: The reason I didn't know how to calculate the integral with respect to $\lambda$ is that I didn't know the measure of the subset $A = \{ (x,x) \mid x \in [0,1]$ of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$.

Comment: You can deduce that the measure must be infinite, because $f$ is the characteristic function of $A$; so $\mu(A)=\int f\,d(\nu\times\mu)$, and that must be infinite because the two iterated integrals are not the same. :) That's a strange way to conclude it, but it is true.

Comment: Wow, that's a really weird result!  How would one prove that if the two iterated integrals are not equal, the integral with respect to the product measure is infinite?  That doesn't seem obvious to me for some reason.

Comment: I had one explanation, but I like this one better. If $f \ge 0$ is jointly measurable and if $\int f\,d(\nu\times\mu) < \infty$, then $f$ is integrable and you can apply Fubini's Theorem to conclude that the iterated integrals are the same and equal to $\int f\,d(\nu\times\mu)$. So, if $A$ is a jointly measurable set and $\int \chi_{A}\,d\nu\,d\mu \ne \int \chi_{A}\,d\mu\,d\nu$, then it must be that $\int \chi_{A}\,d(\nu\times\mu)=\infty$. And, of course that can't happen if both measures are $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: So basically it's the contrapositive statement?  If the iterated integrals are not equal, then $f$ is not in $L^{1}(\,d(\nu \times \mu))$, i.e., its integral is infinite?  I like it, and also that debunks my claim that if the iterated integrals are finite but not equal, then the integral of $f$ with respect to the product measure is finite.  Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome.